# Using mod_rewrite to access hidden files with php check

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of files which are located in an non-public area on the webserver. The files can be pretty large and should be accessible by dynamically generated, temporary links (for instance valid for 1 hour). One solution which is often mentioned is to use a hash and check in php if the hash is still valid, and then stream the file from the php script:

```
<?
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
if (hash == OK)
{
header("Content-Type: ...");
readfile(‘/path/of/file.zip");
}
?>
```

Assuming a very slow user's internet connection it's likely that the php script will timeout after 30 seconds.
I think a better solution is to mod_rewrite, but how is this done properly?:

```
RewriteEngine On
// Check if hash is ok. If true get real filename from php and stream it's content
```

Comment: Why do you think mod_rewrite is a better solution?

Comment: He wrote that: because the verifying php script might timeout before the big file is fully transferred.

Comment: I'd say you should take a closer look at the excellent documentation of the rewriting module. In there the option `RewriteMap` is explained in detail. It offers quite some options to handle dynamic catalogs of rewriting targets.

Comment: arkascha, thanks for the hint RewriteMap. I will check this. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I checked the RewriteMap documentation but unfortunately RewriteMap cannot be used in a directory context.

Comment: A RewriteMap can be used in "a directory context", the rule just needs to go in the appropriate <Directory > block of the **httpd.conf**